# Cannot see dicom image in R

Tags: r, dicom

I am trying to read and see a dicom file. I installed package 'oro.dicom' and was able to read the file with:

```
library(oro.dicom)
abdo <- readDICOMFile("image0.dcm")

extractHeader(abdo$hdr, "Rows")
[1] 2014

extractHeader(abdo$hdr, "Columns")
[1] 2014

extractHeader(abdo$hdr, "Manufacturer", numeric=FALSE)
[1] "...IT Radiology"
```

However, I am not able to see the image:

```
image(t(abdo$img), col=grey(0:64/64), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
Error in t.default(abdo$img) : argument is not a matrix
```

The structure command shows following:

```
str(abdo$img)
int [1:2014, 1:2014, 1:3] 110 51 99 113 52 101 111 53 102 110 ...
```

Following works and a graphic box is displayed but it is only an empty box without any x-ray image:

```
image(t(abdo$img[[1]]), col=grey(0:64/64), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

Why is it not working and how can I correct it? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: with CR-MONO1-10-chest.dcm (http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/CR-MONO1-10-chest.gz) I get following error even while reading it:

```
abdo <- readDICOMFile("CR-MONO1-10-chest.dcm")
Error in readDICOMFile("CR-MONO1-10-chest.dcm") : DICM != DICM
```

With rasterImage following is the error:

```
rasterImage(as.raster(matrix(abdo[[1:3]])))
Error in rasterImage(as.raster(matrix(abdo[[1:3]]))) : 
  argument "xleft" is missing, with no default
```

Following is closer but still does not work:

```
>      rasterImage(abdo$img, 100, 400, 150, 450)
Error in rgb(t(x[, , 1]), t(x[, , 2]), t(x[, , 3]), maxColorValue = max) : 
  color intensity -30, not in [0,1]

>      rasterImage(abdo$img, 100, 400, 150, 450, interpolate=F)
Error in rgb(t(x[, , 1]), t(x[, , 2]), t(x[, , 3]), maxColorValue = max) : 
  color intensity -30, not in [0,1]
>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a 3D array there and `image()` expects a 2D array. It's like they third dimension has data for the RGB layers separately. You can collapse across the third dimension with `rgb`. But this would be much easier to help with if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I don't have many `dcm` files lying around on my computer, nor am I sure which library you are using `readDICOMFile` from.

Comment: @MrFlick is correct.  Try `rasterImage` instead, which happily grabs all three layers of an image array.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. A simple small dicom image (chest x-ray) is available at: http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/CR-MONO1-10-chest.gz . I will also test this image and post the errors with this image. The code is all that I have posted above. With same image it will become like a reproducible example.

Comment: readDICOMFile is from oro.dicom library (I have added this in code above).

Comment: Try `?rasterimage` to see how to use it.  I also don't think you can do `foo[[1:3]]` as the `[[` operator doesn't allow that.

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft: rasterImage code is also not working (see EDIT in the question above.

Comment: Can you please provide the image0.dcm file?  This will help me try to reproduce, and hopefully fix, the problem.

Comment: Which version of **oro.dicom** are you using?  The current version is 0.4.1 on http://cran.r-project.org.

Comment: I have the latest version only: > packageVersion('oro.dicom')
[1] ‘0.4.1’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only valid for the open-source file CR-MONO1-10-chest.dcm (http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/CR-MONO1-10-chest.gz).  I believe that this file is not a valid DICOM file.  According to section 7.1 in Part 10 of the DICOM Standard (available at http://dicom.nema.org) there should be (a) the File Preample of length 128 bytes and (b) the four-byte DICOM Prefix "DICM".  The CR-MONO1-10-chest.dcm starts providing information in the first pair of bytes.

I have added the parameter `skipFirst128 = TRUE` to `readDICOMFile()` and this will be available in the next release of **oro.dicom**.  Thus, one could read the file by using

```
abdo <- readDICOMFile("CR-MONO1-10-chest.dcm", skipFirst128=FALSE, DICM=FALSE)
image(t(abdo$img), col=grey(0:64/64), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

Please note that the file was created almost 20 years ago, I hope that files produced in the recent past will not have this problem.  Thank-you for bringing this error to my attention.  I am always looking for DICOM files that break my code in order to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please also see this link where some more information is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819617/what-could-be-the-reason-for-bad-dicom-image-plot

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the two additional questions in stackoverflow.  I plan to work through them in the next few days.